# Reference Types. Do I understand this correctly?

Tags: c#

This is embarrassing. I learned C# a long time ago and am just now attempting to understand this question about classes (since they are reference types, of course).

Here's the question: If I create two new instances of a class called `Person` and named one instance `P` and the other `Q` (who cares why I'd call it `Q`) and set `P.Name` to `"James"` and then set `Q.Name` to `"Suzie"`, would `P.Name` be set to `"Suzie"`? Or am I not understanding this correctly?

Thanks everyone

Thanks everyone for helping me with this. I assumed what was explained to me was the case. But the explanations in the tutorials I read weren't clear and I haven't had a computer in a few months so as to have tested it out myself.

P.s I chose the first right answer that was clear to me. But noticed several. Thanks again for everyone's help.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. That was a mistake

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423663/null-exception-in-program

Comment: Note: I mean this to be helpful, not rude :). You could have just TRIED this much faster and with fewer characters than it took to type the question. http://ideone.com/b4N2nb. Plus you get into the good habit of discovering how to answer your own questions, have a test bed, etc.

Comment: They would only be the same value if the `Name` property was `static`, or you had some logic in your property `get`/`set` methods to _make_ them equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is NO, changing Q.Name will no affect P.Name.  As in

```
 var p = new Person();
 var q = new Person();
 p.Name = "James";
 q.Name = "Suzie";
```

However, if q points to the p instance, then changing q would also change p.  As in:

```
 var p = new Person();
 var q = p;
 p.Name = "James";
 q.Name = "Suzie";
```

Both q and q Name are now "Suzie".

With data initialisers you can write the first example as:

```
var p = new Person { Name = "James" };
var q = new Person { Name = "Suzie" };
```

which I think is much easier to read.

Comment: @DStanley OP says he learnt C# long time ago. So I thought I should mention a useful new feature in passing.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
// p and q are separate in the below example..

Person p = new Person();
Person q = new Person();

p.Name = "James";
q.Name = "Suzie";

Console.WriteLine(p.Name); // "James"
Console.WriteLine(q.Name); // "Suzie"

// both p and q refer to the same object, so both are "Suzie" in the below example
Person p = new Person();
Person q = p;

p.Name = "James";
q.Name = "Suzie";

Console.WriteLine(p.Name); // "Suzie"
Console.WriteLine(q.Name); // "Suzie"
```

Answer (score 3):

No this is not, because both are **P and Q** different **instance** of class **Person**. Both object or instance define on different memoery location. see this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9afc042.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you create *two* instances? No, they will be 2 separate objects.

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.Name = "James";
Person person2 = new Person();
person2.Name = "Suzie";
Console.WriteLine(person1.Name);
Console.WriteLine(person2.Name);
```

That will print out `James` and then `Suzie`, since they are 2 different objects. If you did this, however:

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.Name = "James";
Person person2 = person1;
person2.Name = "Suzie";
Console.WriteLine(person1.Name);
Console.WriteLine(person2.Name);
```

That will print `Suzie` and `Suzie`. This is because `person1` and `person2` both reference the same object.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely not change the P.Name to Suzie as you have created two instances of the same class, it means that you have allocated two **different memory locations on heap** for these two instance.